# Loading big data Chrome can't refresh or visit under same domain

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome

I use curl inside loop and use flush output buffering data.
Below code in Safari it is fine, but when I test in Chrome and Opera the flush output buffering data works,
but if the printed data contain anchor tag that can't be click, and also under same domain the browser can't visit.
Does anyone know why and how to solve it?

Edit:
1. I did check browser debugger the anchor tag already print.
2. The same browser another window still can visit other domain/website, only freeze under this domain, seems need to wait all loaded or quit the application.
3. Same time user another browser visit same domain it is fine.

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();
foreach ($data as $eachData) {
  // curl
  foreach (.. as ..) {
    // curl 

    // ouput data
    echo '<a href="..">link</a>';
  }
}
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(1);
```

Comment: There's no way to know unless we see a rendered page example. The only reason an anchor tag wouldn't be clickable would have to do with the HTML output, not the php itself.

Comment: I agree with Patrick ^^^ I would check out the links in a browser debugger. Make sure it's outputting the right format for the links.

Comment: it is just a normal anchor tag like `<a href="<?php echo $path['public']; ?>/user/<?php echo $id; ?>">` , and in safari it is ok only in chrome and opera

Comment: I check browser debugger  the url is printed,  if I user right click to open new window it is work to see the right url,   but just can't  loaded in new page, and also can't click to open in same window until data all output.

Comment: Few debugging steps. Make sure the string you output has the right quotation marks " is not as ' and both must be closed and " " cannot contain " for sub string or it will scramble your tag. Try to collect the whole output in a single php variable $html_output for example then echo it at once, not echo while looping, echo it as  a plain text and die afterwards to check what is the actual string before the browser render it. Moder browser can fix html errors for you, if you put <p> <q> <div>/div> firefox will automatically try to guess that you should close the <p> before you open the div.

Comment: So different browser will auto fix differently that's why maybe you are getting different results.

Comment: @Joraid  I can't understand why Chrome,Opera can't visit same domain like freeze  also can't stop it?  seems until loaded all or I quit the application

Comment: well, then try to clear you browsers cache, history, cookies etc and do no-plugin restart for your browser (having all plugins disabled) and see how it goes. Again I want you to try to echo all the output at once, in the loop, save the html text in a variable and then echo the variable at the end after the loop so you will have only one echo.

Comment: @Joraid My Chrome is just install without any plugin and I try reset still same situation. I tried without use flush before but can't wait all loop done to print because that's a lot data and also need to make curl inside each loop and can't use multiple curl in one time.